# How to update table column's value from another table in sequence when table do not relate with each other

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have two tables (A and B). I want to update col3_A with the value col3_B from table B. Col3_B value is in sequence.So Col3_A  has to be updated in sequence as of col3_B.

**Table A:**

```
+--------+--------+--------+
| col1_A | col2_A | col3_A |
+--------+--------+--------+
| A      |      1 | 5      |
| B      |      1 | 3      |
| C      |      1 | 2      |
| D      |      1 | 1      |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

**Table B:**

```
+--------+
| col3_B |
+--------+
|      6 |
|      7 |
|      8 |
|      9 |
+--------+
```

**Required Result:**

```
+--------+--------+--------+
| col1_A | col2_A | col3_A |
+--------+--------+--------+
| A      |      1 |      6 |
| B      |      1 |      7 |
| C      |      1 |      8 |
| D      |      1 |      9 |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

Problem my code only set first two value from col3_B to all col3_A columns and only two value repeat e.g

```
+--------+
| Col3_A |
+--------+
|      6 |
|      7 |
|      6 |
|      7 |
+--------+
```

**my Code:**

```
update A
set A.col2_A = '1', A.col3_A = B.col3_B 
from (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [col] ASC) AS col3_B 
from tableb) B
where A.col1_A in 
(
'A',
'B',
'C',
'D'
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below option as well.Make sure the way we order the records are right though since I am not sure of the business logic in doing that

```
with temp as 
(
   select col1_a,col2_a,col3_a ,
    row_number() over( order by col2_a ) as rn 
   from tablea 
),
 temp1 as 
 ( 
    select col3_b ,row_number() over( order by col3_b ) as rn 
    from tableb
 )
select temp.col1_a,temp.col2_a,temp.col3_a,temp.rn,temp1.col3_b 
into #tt 
from temp join temp1 
on temp.rn=temp1.rn;

 update tablea
 set col3_a=( select tt.col3_b from #tt tt where tt.col3_a=tablea.col3_a)
```

Comment: order by col2_a and order by col3_b might be an issue if the records are not sorted.I would prefer the above solution wherein you create a copy and update the copy .In that way we can test the copy table and make sure that the updates are right and then push this to the main table

Answer (score 0):

Add a unique no to both table1 and table2 and then update the table1 based on table2.

Now the update will be

```
 update table1
 set col3_a=( select col3_b from tableb where a.unqiueid=b.uniqueid);
```

Since col3_a is a character and col3_b is an integer,we need to make sure it does not impact anything else

To create a Unique ID column follow the below steps

step 1 : create a copy of table a using the below query :

```
create table table1_cp
 (
  unique_id integer identity(1,1) primary key,
  col1_A varchar(25),
  col2_a varchar(100),
  col3_a varchar(100)
 );
```

Step 2 :Insert the records from table1 into the cp table

```
select * into table1_cp from table1;
```

Step 3 :Now you can see that the table1_cp has the unique id automatically populated .Now rename the tabl1_cp as table1 after dropping the table1

```
drop table table1;
sp_rename('table_cp','table1');
```

Step 4 :Repeat the same for tableb as well by creating a copy table adding the idnetity column and then inserting records form the original table and finally rename the table

This should be used just for updating purpose or to uniquely identify a record 
Hope this helps

Comment: I edited my question col3_A and col3_b both columns are varchar.
do I still need to add unique number if yes then how to add unique number?
will unique number would be for all rows or it can be applied only to filter result set. for instance if i want to filter where A.col1_A in 
(
'A',
'B',
'C',
'D'
)

should  unique number number be applied to rows containing A,B.C.D.
Please advice with more explanation how to achieve this unique number?

Comment: I have added the steps of how to create Unique identifier .The queries will work for microsoft sql server but if you are using a different database then you will have to create a sequence object and associate it with the table since only sql server has the identity property

Comment: Apama thanks for the explanation.I am running this query against two production tables. I can't change the schema of production  table by adding unique id because it will crash the application. Any other option?

Comment: The only other option that I can think of is just create a copy table with unique id and then do the updates on the copy table and then truncate the main table and insert the values from the copy table into the main table.This might be expensive if the table is too large or it is used in a real time application.Hence first the performance of this needs to be monitored to ensure there are no down times to the application due to this

Comment: Can i use cursors? For instance fetch col3_B from table B and insert into col3_A of table A

Comment: I have added a new solution which is worth trying .but please make sure the records are updated properly by testing it out in a table before implementing in the production