# How to update column of a table from another table in sequence when table don't relate

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am not sure how to update column's value from another table in SQL Server when table don't relate to each other by unique key.

**A**

```
+--------+--------+--------+
| Id     | col2_A | col3_A |
+--------+--------+--------+
| 1      |      3 | 5      |
| 2      |      3 | 3      |
| 3      |      3 | 2      |
| 4      |      3 | 1      |
| 5      |      3 | 8      |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

**B**

```
+--------+--------+
| Id     | Col1_B |
+--------+--------+
|     11 |    6   |
|     12 |    7   |
|     13 |    8   |
|     14 |    9   | 
|     15 |   10   | 
+--------+--------+
```

**Required Result:**

```
+--------+--------+--------+
| Id     | col2_A | col3_A |
+--------+--------+--------+
| 1      |      1 |      6 |
| 2      |      1 |      7 |
| 3      |      1 |      8 |
| 4      |      1 |      9 |
| 5      |      1 |     10 |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

**Pseudo code**

Replace/update Col3_A with col1_B in sequence.

**My code: doesn't work as my code updates Col3_A with random values**

```
Update A
Set col2_A = '1', col3_A = (select col1_B from B)
```

Do I need to use cursor?Please help

Comment: Where are those `Id` values coming from in the expected output?

Comment: And Col2_A? that's not the same as the sample data. Please, make sure your desired output matches the sample data.

Comment: tim Id is FK of different table and Zohar I updated Col2_A = fixed value  and I changed fixed value =1

Comment: How do you decide what value goes to what row? Does it even matter? What happens if you have more rows in table A? do you only update the first x rows (where x is the number of rows in table b)? What happens in the other case, where table B has more rows? Do you update all rows of table A with just the first x number of rows in table B (here x is the number of rows in table A)? Do you have any column in each table to sort the records by? Database tables are unsorted by nature, so unless you have a column to sort the records by, you can't guarantee what value goes to what record.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update table column's value from another table in sequence when table do not relate with each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45344116/how-to-update-table-columns-value-from-another-table-in-sequence-when-table-do)

Comment: Also, why post the exact same question twice just a few days apart?

Comment: I asked question again because it wasn't answered correctly and instead of posting and editing I thought if I ask question in more explaining mode i would get a better result.

Comment: Can you answer my questions in the longer comment? If you can, I might be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE ( id INT, col1 INT, col2 INT );

DECLARE @t2 TABLE ( id INT, col1 INT );

INSERT  INTO @t1
VALUES  ( 1, 3, 5 ),
        ( 2, 3, 3 ),
        ( 3, 3, 2 ),
        ( 4, 3, 1 ),
        ( 5, 3, 8 );

INSERT  INTO @t2
VALUES  ( 11, 6 ),
        ( 12, 7 ),
        ( 13, 8 ),
        ( 14, 9 ),
        ( 15, 10 );


UPDATE  l
SET     l.col1 = '1', l.col2 = r.col1
FROM    ( SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY id ) row ,
                    *
          FROM      @t1
        ) AS l
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY id ) row ,
                            *
                     FROM   @t2
                   ) AS r ON r.row = l.row
WHERE   r.row = l.row;

SELECT  *
FROM    @t1;
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks this solution works!!
Also Zohar Peled I appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
update A, B set col2_A = 1, A.col3_A = B.Col1_B where A.Id = B.Id;
```

## Edit 1

OK, then add pseudo id, and drop it after update.

```
alter table A add column id1 int;
set @n = 0;
update A set id1 = @n := @n+1;
update A, (select @n := @n + 1 id, col1_B from B, (SELECT @n := 0) m) b set A.col3_A = b.col1_B where A.id1 = b.id;
alter table A drop column id1;
```

Comment: read my question again " Table don't relate to each other" so no common column